# How to override MessageBox Help Button path?

Tags: c#, revit

I'm developing a Revit Plug-in.  I want the MessageBox Help Button to go to a link on my website.  However, no matter what path I put in the messagebox arguments, it always just defaults to the link to Revit's help website.  In other forms, I was able to get my help chm to override the Revit Help website, however, I cannot get this messagebox to override to my website.

Here is a sample:

```
DialogResult testA = MessageBox.Show(content, 
"F Title.", 
MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, 
MessageBoxIcon.Information, 
MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1, 
MessageBoxOptions.RightAlign, 
"http://www.blah.com");
```

What can I do?  I'm not going to make a form, so don't suggest it.

Comment: Put the help info in the message box itself so you don't need to override the Help buttons sealed access. Otherwise you're out of luck you'll need to create your own Message Box. It is possible to derive from the messagebox class, but the one function that is acutally useful can not be overridden. So you have to roll your own, sorry...